# Python adding condition in for loop and if else

Tags: python

I wanted to find ids who have converted 'dm_it' from 1 to 0 and again to 1 based on 'date_collected'. I was expecting to see the ids are [2,4,5] but currently, it only gives me [2,4].

Here is my current code.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date_collected': ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05'],
        'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        'dm_it': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


dm_off_group = {}
dm_off_date = {}
dm_transition_count = {}
current_state = None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['id'] not in dm_off_group:
        dm_off_group[row['id']] = 0
        dm_off_date[row['id']] = None
        dm_transition_count[row['id']] = 0
    
    if row['dm_it'] == 1:
        dm_off_group[row['id']] = 1
    
    if row['dm_it'] == 0 and dm_off_group[row['id']] == 1 and dm_off_date[row['id']] is None:
        dm_off_date[row['id']] = row['date_collected']
    
    if row['dm_it'] == 1 and dm_off_group[row['id']] == 1:
        if current_state is None or current_state == 0:
            dm_transition_count[row['id']] += 1
        current_state = 1
    elif row['dm_it'] == 0:
        current_state = 0

dm_transition_ids = [id for id, count in dm_transition_count.items() if count >= 2]

print("IDs with more than two transitions: ", dm_transition_ids)
print(df)
```

Here is my current output

```
IDs with more than two transitions:  [2, 4]
   date_collected  id  dm_it
0      2023-09-01   1      0
1      2023-09-02   1      1
2      2023-09-03   1      1
3      2023-09-04   1      1
4      2023-09-05   1      0
5      2023-09-01   2      1
6      2023-09-02   2      1
7      2023-09-03   2      0
8      2023-09-04   2      1
9      2023-09-05   2      1
10     2023-09-01   3      0
11     2023-09-02   3      1
12     2023-09-03   3      1
13     2023-09-04   3      1
14     2023-09-05   3      1
15     2023-09-01   4      0
16     2023-09-02   4      1
17     2023-09-03   4      0
18     2023-09-04   4      0
19     2023-09-05   4      1
20     2023-09-01   5      1
21     2023-09-02   5      1
22     2023-09-03   5      1
23     2023-09-04   5      0
24     2023-09-05   5      1
```

I am not sure what condition I have to additionally input to consider 'id' 5 correctly in the 'dm_transition_ids'.

Can anyone please help this?

Comment: The obligatory link to [should you be iterating through a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/6385519). I'm not sure what is your goal here but I think it can be done using a combination of group by/ apply/ vectorization

Comment: just 1-0-1 or it may 0-1-0? how about 1-0-1-0, is it still counted?

Comment: 0-1-0 should not be counted, but 1-0-1-0 should be counted. Basically,  any sequence that includes changes from 1 to 0 and then back to 1 will be counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just iterate through dataframe and check the transition. Added remove first transition when starting value = 0. Here is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date_collected': ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05', '2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05'],
        'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        'dm_it': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dm_transition_ids = []

for id, group in df.groupby('id'):
    transitions = 0
    prev_value = None
    start_value = None

    for index, value in enumerate(group['dm_it']):
        if prev_value is None:
            prev_value = value
            start_value = value
        elif prev_value == 1 and value == 0 :
            transitions += 1
        elif prev_value == 0 and value == 1 : 
            transitions += 1
        
        prev_value = value
        
    if start_value==0 : # Ensure it's removed the first transition if start from 0
        transitions=transitions-1
        
    #print(id,transitions) 
    

    if transitions >= 2:
        dm_transition_ids.append(id)

print("IDs with more than two transitions: ", dm_transition_ids)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

[Here is the kaggle link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/edgarsitohang/notebook44d1622788)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that doesn't use itterrows or direct row iterations, but use group by and then numpy vectorized approach:

```
import numpy as np

def is_0_in_bet_1s(arr):
  arr = np.array(arr)
  idx_1 = np.where(arr == 1)[0]
  if len(idx_1):
    idx_0 = np.where(arr==0)
    if len(np.where(arr[idx_1[0]:idx_1[-1]]==0)[0]):
      return True
  return False

df.groupby('id')['dm_it'].apply(lambda x: is_0_in_bet_1s(x.to_numpy()))
```

Output:

```
id
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: dm_it, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```py
transit_ids = []
for ID, values in df.groupby("id")["dm_it"]:
    diffs = values.diff()
    if diffs[diffs.eq(-1)].index.min() < diffs[diffs.eq(1)].index.max():
        transit_ids.append(ID)
```

Group `df` by `id` and take the diffs of the columns `dm_it` (a 1-to-0 transition results in -1 and 0-to-1 transition in 1). Then look if there's a 0-to-1 transition somewhere after a 1-to-0 transition by comparing the min/max of the resp. indices.